# detect Javascript libraries using Jsoup in Java

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup, html-parsing

I know there are ways to detect libraries using JavaScript by checking if a library is a global variable or not `window.Libraryname`. How do I do the same in JSoup?

Note (I know this won't work if the libraries do not register as a global variable and instead defined within a scope (a function) of that application.)

But I am wondering is there way to detect all JavaScript libraries used in a webpage using Java and the Jsoup library? Perhaps parse the page and look for the `<script>` tag? or are there better approaches?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of some HTML and show what you hope to be able to pull out of it?

Comment: So I figured out it is not great to use Jsoup to extract libraries. Since Jsoup is a HTML parser it can't detect any of the `asyc` or `defer` tag that are later added to the DOM. I ended up using GhostDriver + Selenium to get the DOM and have Jsoup to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find all `script` tags of the page.

Then analyze the properties of the `script` tag like: src, innerText, ...

```
if (script.src === 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js') {
   return {
       library: "jquery",
       version: "3.3.1"
   };
}
```

You would need lots of URL's of CDN or string patters to recognize and indentify the libreries.

Edit: add version identification

Comment: this can work but it will treat different version of the same library as two different libraries.

Comment: It would depend on how the identification of URLs is done